# Need to display opportunity and campaign members related to account

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm trying to create PDF of account summary that includes related opportunities and campaign members of an account (hopefully to show a button on account page).

Before working on visualforce page, I am having trouble with apex class.

```
public class AccountRelatedOppCampaignmember {
public List<Opportunity> getOpportunities() {
    List<Opportunity> oppresults = [Select ID, CloseDate, 
                                    Amount, StageName, Name 
                                    from Opportunity where
                                    account=:SelectedValue];
return oppresults;}

public List<CampaignMember> getCampaignmembers() {
    List<CampaignMember> campresults = [Select ID, FirstName,
                                       LastName, Title from 
                                       Campaign Member where
                                       account=:SelectedValue];
return campresults;}}
```

I believe ":SelectedValue" is not the right way to call on particular account, but since I am so new to this, I am just unable to think of a way to phrase? it. I am not even sure if I was going in the right direction... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So...what does `SelectedValue` actually contain?

Comment: If this is a controller extension, as it appears to be, you'll need to get the Account Id from your standard controller. That is the value you'd use in your Apex bind.